# Python Module Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am importing a module

```
from Boards import CheckerBoardModule
```

`CheckerBoardModule` includes a class called `CheckerBoard`

When I want to use it, I need to call `CheckerBoardModule.CheckerBoard`, rather than just `CheckerBoard`.  e.g.

```
class SnakesAndLaddersBoard(CheckerBoardModule.CheckerBoard):

    def __init__(self,width,canvas):
        CheckerBoardModule.CheckerBoard.__init__(self,width,canvas)
        self.snakes  = []
        self.ladders = []
```

Why can't I just used `CheckerBoard`, without the `CheckerBoardModule` prefix?

Answer (score 4):

Because you imported the `CheckerBoardModule` module object, *not* the `CheckerBoard` class. If you want to use just `CheckerBoard`, import *that*:

```
from Boards.CheckerBoardModule import CheckerBoard
```

All that importing does, apart from executing the module if that hasn't already happened, is bind the imported name in your own namespace. `from foo import bar` binds `bar` to whatever `bar` was bound to from `foo`. `from foo import bar as baz` lets you specify a *new* name.